# Adding several strings to the database(Mysql) from several (text input)s

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I can't add strings to the data base, I don't know why, but only empty strings are added.
I think that the main problem is in this part of code (PHP):

```
$word=$_POST[".$i."];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO words(word) VALUES('$word')",$connection);
```

---

I need to add several strings, that I get from (text input)s to the data base

the whole code is here:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Admin Panel (Second Page)</title>    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>


<?php
error_reporting(0);

$user="root";
$pass="";

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost",$user,$pass);

mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS quiz",$connection);
mysql_select_db("quiz",$connection);

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words(id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,word TEXT,PRIMARY KEY(id))",$connection);

    $number = $_POST['numberOfWords'];

echo "<form action=SecondAdminPage.php method=POST ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data'>";



    for($i=1; $i<=$number; $i++)
    {
        echo "<input type='text' name='$i'>";

        $word=$_POST[$i];

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO words(word) VALUES('$word')",$connection);
    }



    echo "<input type='submit' value='Save'>";

?>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: What @Andreas means to say is: **WARNING!** Your code suffers from an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should switch to [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so that you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: That's because you are not getting `$word=$_POST[$i];`... You will get the value once the form is submitted.. but you are inserting without submitting the form.. write your db query in secondadmin.php

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `error_reporting(0)` line to see any PHP errors in your page.

The connection might not be established properly.

Also, the `mysql` extension is deprecated. Use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.